# Pass class with parameter into Class<T>

Tags: java, generics

Is there a way we can pass class type with parameter into a method that accepts `Class<T>`?

Let's say I have this method:

> public  T getProperty(Class type)

Given the method, `getProperty`, which returns whatever type we passed, is there a way I can pass class like `Map` with parameter? Lets say like this:

> getProperty(Map<String, String>.class)

Unfortunately, the code snippet above is giving me compilation error. Using `Map.class` will work though but I would like to eliminate the generic warning and have a strong-typed argument.

Comment: There is no way to accomplish this without a cast that produces the warning, though you can suppress the warning.  (You could redesign getProperty, but that doesn't sound plausible in context.)

Comment: An expected answer. I just hope that there would be a way but looks like this is one of Java's limitation. Thanks man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact use strong-typed argument is meaningless. Because java will erase the type parameter at runtime. All kinds of Map refer to the same Class Object.

Even if you can,it make no difference for `getProperty(Class type)` method whether you pass `Map.class` or `Map<String,String>.class`. So the best thing it can do is return a raw type.